# Is there a difference between bing geocoding and google geocoding?

Tags: google-maps, bing-maps

Here is my question, is there a difference between bing geocoding api and google geocoding api ? If i take for example coordinate returned with bing and plug it in google geocoding function will it return the same address or let say the distance calculated between 2 points, will they return the same value? If you could provide support for your answer that will be awesome. I'm working on a project where i will be using both bing and google api and I'm afraid that mixing the 2 api will cause inefficiency in the project

Comment: Of course there's a difference, they're different software running on different data sets, and this question is off topic for not being about anything in particular.

Comment: @JoshLee really mate ? off topic?not being about anything? This question is targeting people who has worked with the 2 apis, i wanted to know if mixing the 2 apis will cause inaccurate in the results. You need to read the question again i think! i'm not expecting a pathetic answer like "of course there is a difference". Thank you for you precious time.

Comment: What have you tried so far? If you can share some code that shows a specific behaviour that puzzles you, then this is a community where people would be very happy to help. Including myself...This type of questions - I think this is what @JoshLee was referring to - are more for Quora or Reddit, not stackoverflow.

Comment: @rags2riches oh ok i didn't know  i'll will delete it and post again in another forum, but common man! the guy above could have at least explain me that i could elaborate more on the question, not saying that this question is off topic etc... i would have understood. Never mind thanks  ;) and i think he downvoted it too what and arse!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, they are different and will often return different coordinates as there are very few things that can be represented by a single coordinate. Take for example a home address, any coordinate on that property is a valid coordinate. The resolution of a coordinate depends on the number of decimal places. Most platforms are rounding off to 5 or 6 decimal places as 5 decimal places has an accuracy around 1.1 meters, and 6 decimal places around 11cm.

That said, it is also worth pointing out that the terms of use of both platforms do not allow mixing of the services. Bing and Google Maps cannot be used together. That includes taking the coordinate from one and rendering it on the map of the other.